# Converting Numbers to Exponential Form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

can someone explain to me how problems such as:

[image]

are converted into exponential form? I am interested in the logic and method behind this, rather than the answer. Much thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help you understand how exponents work: http://www.mathsisfun.com/exponent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$

b) $y^{-1}$

c)$(x+3)^{\frac{1}{6}}$

d) $(2x-3)^{-11}$

e) $y^\frac{7}{3}$

Notice that $\frac{1}{x^m}=x^{-m}$ and $\sqrt[m] x=x^{\frac{1}{m}}$

Comment: If the person who put a douwnvote could explain, it would be more constructive !!

Comment: I didn't, but could. Don't just hand out the answers, instead offer explanations and hints to let the OP figure out the answer for him-/herself.

Answer (score 0):

For $(a)$, we know that $(\sqrt{x})^2=\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{x}=x$. If you put both sides of $(\sqrt{x})^2=x$ to the power of $\frac{1}{2}$, you can see how to represent $\sqrt{x}$ as an exponent.

Similarly, for $(b)$, we know that we can add the exponents if we're muliplying with the same base: $y^1\cdot y^{(-1)}=y^{1-1}=y^0=1$. Then, if $y\cdot y^{-1}=1$, you can divide both sides by $y$ to find an expression for $\frac{1}{y}$.

If you know these two rules, you should be able to finish the question.

Answer (score 0):

In a previous question you asked ([this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904966/writing-without-negative-exponent)) you got the answer how it works with negative exponents, so i guess your problem is about the roots. For roots you have the general rule: $$\sqrt[n]{x} = x^{\frac{1}{n}},$$
so for example the first question would be $$\sqrt{x} = x^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

There are some exponent rules you just need to remember:

- $\frac{1}{a^n}=a^{-n}$
- $\sqrt[n]{x^m}=x^{\frac{m}{n}}$

With these those exponent rules, you should be able to answer all of the questions.